# Only option under select with display:none style doesn't show the drop down in firefox for windows

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have two drop downs based on selection on first drop down the second drop down is populated. There is no default selection in the first drop down so at start it just shows "select option" in the first drop down. On clicking the drop down icon it will show the list of options. Second drop down as it is not populated so it show just show "select option"

JS fiddle code (updated)
https://jsfiddle.net/1g58yfnw/4/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select id="dropdown1" onChange="onSelection()">
        <option hidden="">Select option</option>
        <option value="1">Cars</option>
        <option value="2">Motor cycles</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dropdown2">
        <option hidden="">Select options</option>
    </select>
```

**CSS**

```
template,
    [hidden] {
        display: none 
    }
```

The code works perfectly fine for IE, chrome and safari whereas it neither shows "select option" nor it shows drop down icon in Firefox for windows. Firefox for Mac works fine. It looks like a bug in Firefox.

Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: one work around could be use ```<option value="-1">Select options</option>``` in both drop down. check out this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/co5w6nsm/)

Comment: @SaadMehmood I shouldn't be able to select the "Select options" once any value is selected (cars or motorcycles) in the drop down

Comment: what you can do hide option with value -1. checkout this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jhywuc5s/1/) @KKD

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per your code your i got one bug where if you select second time same option at first select, on that time thn second select will add again same option so here below simple code will helpfull to you

```js
var cars = {"1":"BMW", "2":"Rolls Royce", "3":"Mercedes", "4":"Lamborgini"};
var motorCycles=["Honda", "Yamaha", "kawasaki"];

function onSelection() {
  var x = $("#dropdown1").find(":selected").val();
  $('#dropdown2 option').remove();
  if( x === "1" ) {
   $.each(cars, function(key, value) {
     $("#dropdown2")
       .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value));
    });
 }
  if( x === "2" ) {
   $.each(motorCycles, function(key, value) {
     $("#dropdown2")
       .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value));
    });
 }
}
```

```css
template,
[hidden] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="dropdown1" onChange="onSelection()">
     <option hidden="">Select option</option>
     <option value="1">Cars</option>
     <option value="2">Motor cycles</option>
  </select>
  <select id="dropdown2">
     <option hidden="">Select options</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes thats bug and taken care too. The main problem is the second drop down initially looks like a text box until some value is selected in the first drop down.

Comment: How its should be displayed initially i mean second dropdown?

if you want second select dropdown after first option selected we can do that....

Comment: Its a known bug in Firefox and fixed in latest versions https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1520430